# How to generate a SHA-3(256) hash in SQL SERVER 2016+

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

How can I generate a SHA-3 (256) hash within SQL Server 2016 ?

HASHBYTES appears to only go up to SHA-2 (256) or SHA-2 (512).

Microsoft BOL isn't giving me a warm and fuzzy, that this is built in anywhere.

```
-- SHA2-256
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'123456');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis);  

-- Output: 0xEC278A38901287B2771A13739520384D43E4B078F78AFFE702DEF108774CCE24

-- SHA3-256  (KECCAK)
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'123456');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA3_256', @HashThis);  

-- Output: NULL
```

Comment: That's because it's not built-in, sorry. Do this client-side or (if you must do it on the DB end) with a CLR function. The CLR function has the problem that it's not built-in to the .NET Framework either; you'll need to pull in custom libraries.

Comment: I had a feeling this was going that way. We are working on a data extract project and need to hash certain data columns out on the export data output. We are using either SSIS or Talend for the export processes, and neither of them have a built in way to do this either.

Comment: Unfortunately (for you) SHA-3 adoption has not been enthusiastic, and support is lacking even in many OS crypto libs (which is why there's no native support in .NET Framework or Core and likely the reason for it not being in SQL Server either).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for that. This is tied to a client request and it appears they want to be bleeding edge on this standpoint.

Comment: Given all of that, I'd still be interested in seeing if anyone has actually gotten something like this to work in an ETL or ELT process and how they did it however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve SHA-3 256 Hashing with a `SQL Server CLR` integration

There is a project on GitHub that has most of the work done for you already and you could easily add SHA3 support to it.

https://github.com/sedenardi/sql-hashing-clr

There is no way of SHA3-256 hashing with pure dotnet core. I recommend you make use of BouncyCastle library (https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) that has a SHA3-256 support. There is a nuget library package that is a wrapper on top of BouncyCastle and could make SHA3-256 hashing relatively easy to achieve. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SHA3.Net/. You'll need to use this package and update `HashUtil.cs`

Pre Req: Build CLR .dll

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
-- include NugetPackage to help with SHA-3 hashing

public class HashUtil
{
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
    public static SqlBinary GetHash(SqlString algorithm, SqlBytes src)
    {
        if (src.IsNull)
            return null;

        switch (algorithm.Value.ToUpperInvariant())
        {
            case "MD5":
                return new SqlBinary(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(src.Stream));
            case "SHA1":
                return new SqlBinary(SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(src.Stream));
            case "SHA2_256":
                    return new SqlBinary(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(src.Stream));
            case "SHA2_512":
                    return new SqlBinary(SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(src.Stream));
            -- add SHA3-256
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("HashType", "Unrecognized hashtype: " + algorithm.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Deploy the CLR .dll to SQL Server

   For reference here is Microsoft's documentation on how to deploy a CLR .dll

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/deploying-clr-database-objects?view=sql-server-ver15
2. Deploy Function to SQL Server

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetHashHybrid(@algorithm NVARCHAR(4000),@input VARBINARY(MAX))
    RETURNS VARBINARY(8000) WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN ( 
        SELECT dbo.GetHash(@algorithm,@input)
    )
    END
   ```
3. Call dbo.GetHash

   ```
   DECLARE @INPUT VARCHAR(MAX);
   SELECT @INPUT = REPLICATE(CAST('test1' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),2000);
   SELECT dbo.GetHash('MD5',CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),@INPUT));
   ```

This example shows MD5 hashing but demonstrates the concept of how you can use CLR to create hashing functionality that is not supported "out of the box" from SQL Server currently.